# Wakeups logs iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, uiwebview

I have an app based on Cordova, where I have added some native code. Now many clients reports to me app crash with this log:

```
{"timestamp":"2017-01-19 10:49:12.99 +0100","bug_type":"142","os_version":"iPhone OS 10.2 (14C92)","incident_id":"7E3CD91B-9427-4CB5-B3AC-D77E36D2912A"}
Date/Time:       2017-01-19 10:45:43 +0100
OS Version:      iPhone OS 10.2 (Build 14C92)
Architecture:    arm64
Report Version:  19

Command:         MYAppName
Path:            /var/containers/Bundle/Application/37EF43DB-708B-41CD-96C8-6793C90BE61C/MYAppName.app/MYAppName
Version:         1.0.2 (0.0.36)
Parent:          launchd [1]
PID:             823

Event:           wakeups
Wakeups:         45001 wakeups over the last 209 seconds (215 wakeups per second average), exceeding limit of 150 wakeups per second over 300 seconds
Duration:        208.99s
Steps:           49

Hardware model:  iPad4,2
Active cpus:     2
```

What is this "wakeups"? Serveces that wakeup the app when this is in background?
And if are these.. can be `UIWebView`?

Comment: Any update? Did you resolve this issue. My app at times freezes the whole phone I believe this is my route cause.

Comment: not yet, I'm sorry

Answer (score 0):

There is a limitation of Safari, I also experienced the same pain especially on iPhone and iPad.

Also refer to:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53183613/4468648