# MacOS wakeups per second error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, macos

Building a Rails app (ruby 2.4.0p0 / Rails 5.1.4) and testing locally with my Macbook air (MacOS High Sierra 10.13.2) and I keep running into this problem:

> 45001 wakeups over the last 241 seconds (187 wakeups per second
>   average), exceeding limit of 150 wakeups per second over 300 seconds

I think this might have to do with the fact that I'm using Mongoid (6.1.0) as a database, but I'm not sure. It's my first time playing around with Mongo.

Any thoughts on how I might be able to address this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is browser limited, I also experienced the same especially on iPhone and iPad.

So the safari browser limits the max number of wakeups. (E.g. you might get massive event call back in the front end)

Set the internal to be long, or merge some intervals into less callbacks.

Or you may have many video with ultra framerates